# ExtJS 7 with npm - Cannot satisfy requirements for "google"

Tags: extjs7

Trying to add a google map to an ExtJS app that's using the "open tooling" (i.e. npm) scheme.

```
$ ext-gen app -t moderndesktopminimal -m theme-material -n App
$ cd app
$ npm install --save @sencha/ext-google
$ vim app.json # add "google" to the "requires" array
$ npm start
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
> webpack-dev-server --env.profile=desktop --env.browser=yes --env.verbose=no

i [ext]: ext-webpack-plugin v7.0.2, Ext JS v7.0.0.156 Commercial Edition, Sencha Cmd v7.0.0.40, webpack v4.39.3n/a
i [ext]: Starting development build for extjs
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:1962/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from ./
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
i [ext]: Processing Build Descriptor : desktop (development environment)
i [ext]: [ERR] Cannot satisfy requirements for "google"!
i [ext]: [ERR]    The following versions cannot be satisfied:
i [ext]: [ERR]       App: google (No matches!)
i [ext]: [ERR] Cannot resolve package requirements
******************************************
i [ext]: Cannot satisfy requirements for "google"!
******************************************
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

Grrr.... I ended up spending a support credit on this only to find it's in their docs but isn't clear at all.

I needed to add the path to the module to packages>dir in the workspace.json file to make this work. Adding other addon Ext components like charts or d3 didn't require this step but it's necessary for the google one.

Frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the path to workspace.json. this applies to ext-modern-locale too.

[Sencha Addon Reference](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/guides/getting_started/getting_started_addons/getting_started_with_npm.html#getting_started-_-getting_started_addons/getting_started_with_npm_-_for_workspaces__delcare_packages_in_the_workspace)